# Why am I getting error with this c++ code?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int volume(int l, int w, int h);
int main()
{
    int y, x, z;
    cout << "Enter The Length, Width And Height Respectively " << endl;
    cin >> y >> x >> z;
    volume(y, x, z);
    cout << "The Volume is " << volume();
    return 0;
}

int volume()
{
    return l*w*h;
}
```

I am getting three errors as follows:-

> error 'l' was not declared in the scope.
>   error 'h' was not declared in the scope.
>   error 'w' was not declared in the scope.

Please help me rectify my error.

Comment: How about changing `int volume (){` to `int volume(int l, int w, int h){` ?

Comment: The compiler is doing a perfect job pointing you to your mistakes

Answer (score 2):

Your definition of `volume` doesn't match its prototype. It needs to have the three parameters `l`, `w`, and `h` as you defined in your function prototype.

```
int volume (int l, int w, int h){
    return l*w*h;
}
```